syno crowdsec+fail2ban not doing enough
I'm trying to lock down my Syno DS918+. I have SSH exposed on a non-standard port. Recently I'm banning 10-30 new IPs each day. The brute-force "Protection" is set to 3 failed login attempts within 999 minutes (max allowed), banning for 90 days.
In the main interface, I installed CrowdSec. Other than the syno "Package Center" telling me that it is "running", I have no indication that it is doing anything. When I ssh in to the syno, every cscli command seems to work but all start with
root@syno:~# cscli collections list
WARN[10-04-2024 08:14:02 AM] Crowdsec is not the latest version. Current version is 'v1.3.0' and the latest stable version is 'v1.6.0'. Please update it! 
WARN[10-04-2024 08:14:02 AM] As a result, you will not be able to use parsers/scenarios/collections added to Crowdsec Hub after CrowdSec v1.6.0 
...

The package was installed via the SynoCommunity, I believe based on https://github.com/CyberMind-FR/spksrc-crowdsec. This is a fork of https://github.com/crowdsecurity/spksrc-crowdsec. Neither has seen updates recently. I suspect that the cscli warnings are because the package is otherwise unmaintained.
I'm also running a docker stack and have fail2ban running in a docker container. I believe this is geared to protect the apps within the docker stack and not the main DSM, namely the exposed SSH port. (While I can mount DSM log files to inside the fail2ban container, I don't think the container can affect the Syno native firewall.)
Is there a better way to install/maintain/update CrowdSec on Syno, or can I influence the version installed within the Syno package? (Are there other steps I can be taking other than locking down external access and security-through-obscurity changing default ports?)
In the end, fail2ban is a reactive approach, and I suspect that the syno "Protection" configuration is doing effectively the same thing. I'd like a more proactive approach as suggested by CrowdSec.

You should not expose a NAS to the internet in the first place, especially not administrative ports.

I've only exposed SSH, nothing more. That is the port that is getting brute-force attempts. I understand the security premise of exposing ports in general, are you saying that Syno's SSH compared to other SSH implements is not safe to expose? Or that SSH itself should not be exposed, preferring VPNs? @GeraldSchneider

I guess this is a serious question, @GeraldSchneider: if it's unsafe to export SSH (xz excepted, of course), what is safe to open to the internet? It is likely "always best" to have a bastion host for ssh access into the private network, but that's often difficult for many reasons (convenience notwithstanding).
